# iOS execute method after constraints are placed in a view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm using autoLayout in a view and I want to execute a method after constraints are placed, because I've an image and I need the real frame.

I'm using iOS 8 SDK.

This is the method that I want to execute

```
- (void)addGradientOverlayToQuestion {
    CALayer *questionLayer = self.questionImage.layer;
    CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    maskLayer.colors = @[(id)([UIColor blackColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor)];
    maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.7);
    maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
    maskLayer.frame = questionLayer.bounds;
    questionLayer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

I tried

```
[self layoutIfNeeded]
[self addGradientOverlayToQuestion];
```

and it's the same, also I tried

```
[self.questionView layoutSubviews];
```

but the image looks too big.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a little more details.  Your question is slightly confusing

Comment: How can I know that the frame has been updated by autoLayout? (In a view)

Comment: try to call `layoutIfNeeded` method in order to make views relayout accordingly to your constraints, and after that try calling your method. This should work

Comment: I tried but still not working. I've updated the question with some code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to override layoutSubviews in your UIView to get the moment after the subviews have been laid out?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.hasAddedGradient) {
         [self removeGradient]; // Remove previously added gradient
    }

    self.hasAddedGradient = YES;
    [self addGradientOverlayToQuestion];
}
```

So make sure you track if the gradient has been added already and make sure you can remove it so you can add it again. This method should be repeatable.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I still have the same problem that the image looks so big. It seems like the autoLayout hasn't effect

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is also a good candidate. Please NSLog your frames with NSStringFromCGRect like NSLog(@"Found rect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame))

Comment: I'm in a view, not in a ViewController. Also I've a xib and I'm using size classes. This is the log of the frame of one UIView that I have in the xib : {{15, 62}, {570, 448}}

Comment: So that's the correct CGRect or not? You simply need to NSLog the frame and see if it's the size and position you expect, if that size is expected your problem has a different reason.

Comment: The CGRect is incorrect, I'm using an iPhone 5 simulator to test it

Comment: It's really hard to see where it goes wrong from here. If you have a button somewhere put a breakpoint there and debug into or log the CGRect from there. I have the feeling that perhaps the CGRect is correct but you're seeing the image spill over out of it's view or something in that direction. Try to use Debug View Hierarchy to see how everything's arranged at runtime.